# Locate Tray Icon

Tags: delphi, icons, tray, locate

I'm having problem locating tray icon (in px) on traybar.

I can locate tray but not icon as well. This is the code I'm using:

```
unit uTrayIconPosition;

interface

uses
  Types;

function GetTrayIconPosition(const AWnd: THandle; const AButtonID: Integer; var APosition: TRect): Boolean;

implementation

uses
  Windows, CommCtrl, Classes, SysUtils;

function EnumWindowsFunc(AHandle: THandle; AList: TStringList): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  P: array [0..256] of Char;
  S: string;
begin
  if GetClassName(AHandle, P, SizeOf(P) - 1) <> 0 then
  begin
    S := P;
    if S = AList[0] then
    begin
      AList[0] := IntToStr(AHandle);
      Result := False;
    end
    else
      Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := True;
end;

function FindClass(AName: string; AHandle: THandle; var AChild: THandle): Boolean;
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    List := TStringList.Create;
    try
      List.Add(AName);
        EnumChildWindows(AHandle, @EnumWindowsFunc, LParam(List));
      if List.Count > 0 then
      begin
        AChild := StrToInt(List[0]);
        Result := True;
      end;
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

// --- Handle of notify Wnd

```
function GetTrayNotifyWnd: THandle;
var
  ShellTray: THandle;
  TrayNotify: THandle;
  ToolBar: THandle;
begin
    Result := 0;
  ShellTray := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  if ShellTray <> 0 then
    if FindClass('TrayNotifyWnd', ShellTray, TrayNotify) then
      if IsWindow(TrayNotify) then
        if FindClass('ToolbarWindow32', TrayNotify, ToolBar) then
                Result := ToolBar;
end;
```

// --- Finding Tray rect

```
function GetTrayWndRect: TRect;
var
  R: TRect;
  Handle: THandle;
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;
begin
    Handle := GetTrayNotifyWnd;
    if Handle > 0 then
    begin
        GetWindowRect(Handle, R);
        Result := R;
    end
  else
  begin
      Width := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    Height := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    Result := Rect(Width - 40, Height - 20, Width, Height);
  end;
end;
```

// --- Main function that should locate tray icon

```
function GetTrayIconPosition(const AWnd: THandle; const AButtonID: Integer; var APosition: TRect): Boolean;
var
  hWndTray: HWND;
  dwTrayProcessID: DWORD;
  hTrayProc: THandle;
  iButtonsCount: Integer;
  lpData: Pointer;
  bIconFound: Boolean;
  iButton: Integer;
  dwBytesRead: DWORD;
    ButtonData: TTBBUTTON;
  dwExtraData: array [0..1] of DWORD;
  hWndOfIconOwner: THandle;
  iIconId: Integer;
//  rcPosition: TPoint;
  rcPosition: TRect;
begin
    Result := False;

  hWndTray := GetTrayNotifyWnd;
  if hWndTray = 0 then
    Exit;

    dwTrayProcessID := 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndTray, dwTrayProcessID);
    if dwTrayProcessID <= 0 then
        Exit;

    hTrayProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, dwTrayProcessID);
    if hTrayProc = 0 then
        Exit;

    iButtonsCount := SendMessage(hWndTray, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);
  lpData := VirtualAllocEx(hTrayProc, nil, SizeOf(TTBBUTTON), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (lpData = nil) or (iButtonsCount < 1) then
    begin
        CloseHandle(hTrayProc);
        Exit;
    end;

    bIconFound := False;
    for iButton :=0 to  iButtonsCount - 1 do
    begin
        dwBytesRead := 0;
        SendMessage(hWndTray, TB_GETBUTTON, iButton, LPARAM(lpData));
        ReadProcessMemory(hTrayProc, lpData, @ButtonData, SizeOf(TTBBUTTON), dwBytesRead);
        if dwBytesRead < SizeOf(TTBBUTTON) then
            Break;

    dwExtraData[0] := 0;
    dwExtraData[1] := 0;
        ReadProcessMemory(hTrayProc, Pointer(ButtonData.dwData), @dwExtraData, SizeOf(dwExtraData), dwBytesRead);
        if dwBytesRead < SizeOf(dwExtraData) then
            Break;

        hWndOfIconOwner := THandle(dwExtraData[0]);
        iIconId := Integer(dwExtraData[1]);
        if hWndOfIconOwner = AWnd then
        if iIconId = AButtonID then
            begin
            if (ButtonData.fsState or TBSTATE_HIDDEN) = 1 then
                Break;

        SendMessage(hWndTray, TB_GETITEMRECT, iButton, LPARAM(lpData));
        ReadProcessMemory(hTrayProc, lpData, @rcPosition, SizeOf(TREct), dwBytesRead);
        if dwBytesRead < SizeOf(TRect) then
          Break;

        MapWindowPoints(hWndTray, 0, rcPosition, 2);
        APosition := rcPosition;
        bIconFound := True;
        Break;
      end;
    end;

    if not bIconFound then
        APosition := GetTrayWndRect;
    VirtualFreeEx(hTrayProc, lpData, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hTrayProc);
    Result := True;
end;

end.
```

Algo detect # of Tray icons, but doesn't map each of them.

### This is added:

Cause this solution works only under XP and 32bit systems I've tried following:

```
{$EXTERNALSYM Shell_NotifyIconGetRect}
function Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(const _in: NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER; var _out: TRECT): HRESULT; stdcall;

implementation

function Shell_NotifyIconGetRect; external 'Shell32.dll' name 'Shell_NotifyIconGetRect';
```

Delphi 2007 doesn't have this function mapped and also this structure:

```
type
  NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER = record
    cbSize  : DWORD;
    hWnd    : HWND;
    uID     : UINT;
    guidItem: TGUID;
end;
  PNOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER = ^NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER;
```

After I've created my tray icon with Shell_NotifyIcon I've tried to pass that _NOTIFYICONDATA structure hWND to this new NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER structure >

```
var
  R: TRect;
  S: NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER;

FillChar(S, SizeOf(S), #0);
S.cbSize := SizeOf(NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER);
S.hWnd := ATrayIcon.Data.Wnd;
S.uID := ATrayIcon.Data.uID;

Result := Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(S, R) = S_OK;
```

This is working correctly and I receive in Rect structure upper left corner of my Tray Icon.

Comment: -1 for several reasons. There is no question here. It's a "please debug my program for me" question. There's no indication of where the code goes wrong, showing no effort at solving the problem before posting here.

Comment: Thanks for negative marks, I really appreciate this cause I've invested zero efforts to solve this problem and came here to ask cause I'm very lazy.
I wrote this code many years ago and it was working properly on 32bit WinXP but it's not working on Win7 64bit.
I need to locate icon in order to show my custom dialog near it (with pointer etc.)

Comment: @Ivan It's not going to work on 64 bit Windows. It may very well not even work on 32 bit Windows 7 because private implementation detail tends to change between versions. But it can't work on 64 bit Windows because you are trying to read memory structures from a 64 bit process. But your 32 bit version of `TBBUTTON` is a different size and layout from the 64 bit version. When are you showing your custom dialog? Is it in response to user action? Anyway, who says your icon will even be visible. The user might have hidden it.

Comment: Or windows itself might be hiding it.

Comment: Please note that your solution — to call `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` — will cause your program to **fail to load** on earlier Windows versions that don't yet offer that function.

Comment: I tried to fill in the NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER structure as you did, but it throws an error: "Cannot access protected symbol TCustomTrayIcon.data"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 7 and upwards you should use the API function that MS introduced for this very purpose: [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378426.aspx).

Your current code is failing for one or more of the following reasons:

1. You are trying to read 32 bit versions of the structures from a 64 bit process. In this case `TTBBUTTON` has a different layout and size under 64 bits and the process you are attacking is 64 bit explorer.
2. The implementation (details of which you are relying on) of the notification area has changed between XP and 7. I do not know whether or not this is true, but it could be!

Comment: I'm aware of problem now. Thanks for helping. There is no solution under Win64bit and I don't know why Win hiding this from user... Very idiotic and without any purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` does exactly what you need. That leaves you with Vista. If your existing code works in Vista 32 bit then it's easy enough to make it work in Vista 64. You just need to ensure that you get a `TTBBUTTON` declaration that is correct for a 64 bit process. That's not too hard to achieve.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. Anyway I'm trying to receive NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER structure and on MSDN I found that I can do that either over uID and hWND or using GUID. I have TrayIcon.Data that contains hWND but uID of icon is zero.

Comment: I don't know how to generate valid NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here and comments are not appropriate for a new question.

Comment: This is valid structure:
type
  NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER = record
    cbSize  : DWORD;
    hWnd    : HWND;
    uID     : UINT;
    guidItem: TGUID;
end;

and this is function that I should use:
function Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(const _in: NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER; _out: TRECT): BOOL; stdcall;

I don't know how to get uID or GUID in order to receive proper function result.

Comment: uID is the same value you passed to Shell_NotifyIcon

Comment: It's working. I've added solution in my first question. Thanks.