# Using the Shell_NotifyIconGetRect function for TTrayIcon

Tags: winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have developed a small application, which places an icon in the system tray, and displays a form above it.

When I filled in the `TNotifyIconData` structure myself and called the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function to add the icon, I could use the `TNotifyIconIdentifier` structure to use the `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` function and get the location of the icon, thus displaying the form above it.

I now use the `TTrayIcon` component, which is easier to deal with, but now I can not set the `TNotifyIconIdentifier` structure correctly to do what I wanted.

I declared the structure on the form as follows:

```
...
TrayIconForTest: TTrayIcon;
...
public
  TrayIconIdentifier: TNotifyIconIdentifier;
...
```

And I fill it in with the event handler `FormCreate` like this:

```
with TrayIconIdentifier do
begin
  cbSize := SizeOf(TNotifyIconIdentifier);
  hWnd := Handle;
  uID := AllocateHwnd(WindowProc);
  GuidItem := GUID_NULL;
end;
```

Then I wrapped the `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect` function like this:

```
function TTesterForm.GetTrayIconRect(var R: TRect): Boolean;
var
 FResult: HRESULT;
begin
  FResult :=  Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(TrayIconIdentifier, R);
  if FResult = S_OK then
    Result := True
  else
  begin
    MessageBox(0, PWideChar('The system tray icon location could not be found. '+SysErrorMessage(FResult, 0)+'.'), 'Shell_NotifyIconGetRect Error', MB_OK or MB_ICONSTOP);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

But when I call the `GetTrayIconRect` function, it displays the error.

The problem seems to be with the TNotifyIconIdentifier build, but I did not find what I was doing wrong. I checked the Vcl.ExtCtrls unit, and found no direction.

When I tried to transfer the data from TTrayIcon like this (I saw someone who posted this solution):

```
with TrayIconIdentifier do
begin
  FillChar(TrayIconIdentifier, SizeOf(TrayIconIdentifier), #0);
  cbSize := SizeOf(TNotifyIconIdentifier);
  hWnd := TrayIconForTest.Data.Wnd;
  uID := TrayIconForTest.Data.uID;
  GuidItem := GUID_NULL;
end;
```

I received the error "Cannot access protecetd symbol TCustonTrayIcon.Data".

What can I fix in the code to properly use the Shell_NotifyIconGetRect function?

Comment: Why don't you use Shell_NotifyIcon

Comment: @David you're right, it's just easier to get by with TTrayIcon... otherwise, I should also set up a mouse event handler in the icon myself, instead of just using `OnMouseMove`, and more... you'll probably figure that out for yourself :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is any easier! You already had a solution. I know that I do it myself and call `Shell_NotifyIcon` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AllocateHwnd()` for the `uID` is absolutely wrong. You need to use the actual ID number that `TTrayIcon` registered for its icon.

Your second code is the correct way to go. However, as you have discovered, the [`Data`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomTrayIcon.Data) property is *protected*, so you can't access it directly. Fortunately, it is not *private*, so you can reach it indirectly using an accessor class, eg:

```
type
  TTrayIconAccess = class(TTrayIcon)
  end;

FillChar(TrayIconIdentifier, SizeOf(TrayIconIdentifier), #0);
with TrayIconIdentifier do
begin
  cbSize := SizeOf(TrayIconIdentifier);
  if (TTrayIconAccess(TrayIconForTest).Data.uFlags and NIF_GUID) = 0 then
  begin
    hWnd := TTrayIconAccess(TrayIconForTest).Data.Wnd;
    uID := TTrayIconAccess(TrayIconForTest).Data.uID;
  end else
    GuidItem := TTrayIconAccess(TrayIconForTest).Data.guidItem;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out. Interestingly, I saw in one of the posts someone who posted the way to access the Data property, how did it work for him?
In the Vcl.ExtCtrls unit, defined `FData.uID := AllocateHwnd(WindowProc);` So I tried to define it that way.

Comment: @yonni "*how did it work for him?*" - I can't answer that without seeing the original post. "*In the Vcl.ExtCtrls unit, defined `FData.uID := AllocateHwnd(WindowProc);`*" - well, that is just downright stupid. The VCL should not be doing that. I would suggest filing that as a bug to Embarcadero. "*So I tried to define it that way*" - which won't work, because every call to `AllocateHWnd()` creates a new window, thus the value will be different each time.

Comment: Well, this is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502418/locate-tray-icon . I should also note that the definition in vcl.ExtCtrls is for TNotifyIconData and defines it as follows: `FData.Wnd := AllocateHwnd(WindowProc);` `FData.uID := FData.Wnd;`